# useEffect does not trigger after store update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to retrieve data from Api and save it in Redux store then print it on screen.

I'm using functional components.

Then when data cames back `embedToken` stay `undefined` , I think it should get updated when store 'refreshes'

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { requestEmbedToken } from './redux/actions'

function App(props) {
  const [embedToken, setEmbedToken] = useState(props.token);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.token === undefined) {
      props.requestToken();
      console.log(props.token)

      setEmbedToken(props.token)
    }
  }, [props]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          Here's the token {JSON.stringify(embedToken)}
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  token: state.embedToken,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return ({
    requestToken: () => dispatch(requestEmbedToken())
  })
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

**Actions**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const saveEmbedToken = token => ({
    type: 'SAVE_EMBED_TOKEN',
    payload: {
        token
    }
})
export const requestEmbedToken = () => (dispatch) => {

    return axios.get('http://localhost:7071/api/getpbiTokens')
        .then(response => {
            console.log("token embed", response)
            dispatch(saveEmbedToken(response.data.token))
        })
}
```

**Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

function reportingActions(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SAVE_EMBED_TOKEN':
            return {
                ...state,

                embedToken: action.payload.token

            }
        default: // need this for default case
            return state

    }
}
const reportingReducers = combineReducers({
    reportingActions
})
export default reportingReducers
```

Comment: I think that it's something related to the dispatching action before the async  return of requestEmbedToken as indicated [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/#actionsjs-asynchronous)

Comment: Move `setEmbedToken` outside the condition and update the dependency to `props.token` so it is set every time the token updates. Currently you only set it to undefined if the token is undefined since the code is synchronous. Maybe you want to make the token request async and await it in the effect callback? See using async functions in effect hook.

Comment: Try   useEffect(() => {
...
  }, [props.token]);

Comment: @lissettdm tried but not working, ( My api is sending data back correctly)

Comment: Did you check if this action SAVE_EMBED_TOKEN is called and the state is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual path to the token is `state.reportingActions.embedToken` not `state.embedToken`

Fix this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  token: state.embedToken,
})
```

Comment: That's it, but why it's `state.reportingActions.embedToken` and not `state.embedToken`? in reducer I set embedToken only

Comment: because `combineReducers({ reportingActions })` returns redux state and `reportingActions` is its property

Comment: Ok I'm used to Angular NGRX store and it doesn't add name of reducer as state property unless you add it in the reducer return  object